# Partition of Unity - function construction in proof of theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Prove there exists $ \psi: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that:

1. $ \psi \in C^1(\mathbb R^n)$.
2. $\psi(0)=1$.
3. $\forall x \in \mathbb R^n, \space  0 \leq \psi(x) \leq 1$.
4. $ \operatorname{supp}(\psi) \subseteq B_1(0)$ (the open unit ball).
5. $\forall x \in B_{\frac{1}{2}}(0), \space \psi(x) > 0$.

**My attempt so far:**
Let $n \in \mathbb N$. Define $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as

$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
64n^2x^3-16nx  & x\in(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}},\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}})  \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

This function is continuous and integrable. So an antiderivative of $f$:

$$ F(x) =
\begin{cases}
16n^2x^4-8nx^2+1  & x\in(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}},\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}})  \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

Now, define $\psi_j (x_1,\dots,x_n) = F(x_j)$ for all $1 \leq j \leq n$, and  finally define $\psi(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \underset{j=1}{\overset{n}{\LARGE\Pi}}\psi_j(x).$
$\psi$ fulfills the first four conditions, but I can't prove (and I'm not even sure that it's possible) that it has the last property.

1. $\psi$ is obviously $C^1$ since it is a product of $C^1$ functions.
2. Indeed $\psi(0) = 1$ as the product of $F(0) = 1$.
3. Since $F$ has global maximum at $(0,1)$ and its global minimum is $0$, as the product of such functions $\psi(x)$ does fulfill $\forall x \in \mathbb R^n, \space  0 \leq \psi(x) \leq 1$.
4. By norm equivalence, $\psi(x)\neq0$ if and only if $\forall x_j, \space |x_j|<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ so $\lVert x \rVert \leq \sqrt{n} \lVert x \rVert _\infty \lt \frac{1}{2}$.

Well obviously I can gurantee $\psi$ isn't 0 in $B_{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}}(0)$, but not necessarily in the ball with radius $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Try defining the function radially. Find an appropriate $g: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ so that $F(x)=g(||x||)$